# Swiper js with thumbs

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have two slider on one page. The first slider works fine, but on the second one the thumbs do not work, they are not active and do not move with the main slider.

```js
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      slidesPerView: 4,
      freeMode: true,
      watchSlidesProgress: true,
    });
    var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      thumbs: {
        swiper: swiper,
      },
    });
    var swiper3 = new Swiper(".mySwiper3", {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      slidesPerView: 4,
      freeMode: true,
      watchSlidesProgress: true,
    });
    var swiper4 = new Swiper(".mySwiper4", {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      thumbs: {
        swiper: swiper,
      },
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change 'swiper' with 'swiper3' for second slider like this

```
    var swiper4 = new Swiper(".mySwiper4", {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      thumbs: {
        swiper: swiper3,
      },
    });
```